# SharePoint Console program cannot load System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0 assembly

Tags: sharepoint, assemblies

I'm writing a console application, that uses SharePoint object model to manipulate data inside of SharePoint.

There are two variables:

```
SPWeb spWeb
string formsUser   //username
```

and I'm trying to resolve user

```
SPUser userF = spWeb.EnsureUser(formsUser);
```

This line keeps throwing exception:

> Could not load file or assembly  "System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the specified file.

My project's Target framework is .Net Framework 3.5. I have reference to `System.Web.Extensions.dll`, version 3.5.0.0..

What I cannot understand:

1. Why is my application expecting this assembly in version `4.0.0.0` and not in `3.5.0.0` ?
2. Why this line would be throwing exception regarding `System.Web.Extensions`, if everything in this line is about `Microsoft.SharePoint` assembly

**Update:**
in above example I'm using forms based user, so the string is something like: `i:0#.f|someprovider|john.doe`. If I use Windows based user instead, so `i:0#.w|domain\john.doe`, this exception is not thrown.

Is there any chance, that `SPUser` is secretly trying to use `System.Web.Extensions`, and fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

The `app.config` file in my application contains `system.web/membership` and `roleManager` sections. And there was reference to the `System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0`

```
<add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" 
     type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```